# why is this click event failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so i am stumped if you go to my [site](http://kingdomshopper.com/) and click the right center "Take a Quick Tour >>>" ..i get this lightbox that appears and i want to close it programmatically and in firebug i can see the x is id "rokbox-close" but running this in firebug

```
document.getElementById('rokbox-close').click();
```

but i get this error

```
 TypeError: document.getElementById("rokbox-close").click is not a function
```

any ideas how to do this

i can run this

```
document.getElementById("rokbox-close")
```

and get the element but the click function fails...i dont have jquery installed so i was wondering if there is a javascript thing i am missing

Comment: How is the event attached? Does `onclick()` work?

Comment: onclick on where ...on the other handler??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all browsers have a "click()" function associated with buttons and anchors and etc.  IE does (I think), but (for example) Firefox doesn't.

*edit* — wow according to MDC, Firefox 5 [will support this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click).

If you were using a framework such as jQuery, then that code might allow you to do what you want. (With jQuery you definitely can.)

(Also, strictly speaking, we're not talking about an *event* here.  We're talking about the ability to trigger the event handling mechanism programatically.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use simple JavaScript istead of 'click' use 'onclick':

```
document.getElementById("rokbox-close").onclick = youClickHandlerFunction
```

If you use jQuery use:

```
$('#rokbox-close').click(youClickHandlerFunction)
```

See more info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html
Or here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

The click() function is something that is not supported by all browsers. You're probably thinking of the click handler that jQuery provides.

For a more complete view of why click() isn't universally handled, check out this link, which covers the long and twisty history of event handling across different browsers:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html